# window variable defined in a window function not seen outside

Tags: javascript, global-variables, canvasjs

I have defined as window a new instance of a CanvasJS object inside a window function and called it chart. This object is not seen in a function managing a slider movement. The scope was to move an horizontal line in the chart coherently with the slider moving. Here the code

1. ajax intercepts the postback and 
   a. fill a container with the resulting html code and scripts
   b. lunch a function to create e new chart

   ```
   $("#desktop_new_alarm_research").submit(function(e) {

   e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.

   var form = $(this);
   var url = ajax_url+'Login/getResearchResultsForNewPriceAlarms';

   $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: url,
          data: form.serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
          success: function(data)
          {
              var response = JSON.parse(data);             

           $('#research_results_container').html(response.rendered_page);

              if(response.state == 'success'){

                  if(response.galenic_made == false){



                       renderPriceGraphs(response.chart_name, response.min_price_usd, response.max_price_usd,response.factory_made,response.galenic_made,response.factory_made_max_min_graph_prices,response.factory_made_avg_graph_prices_stats);
                  }

                  if(response.galenic_made == true){
                       renderPriceGraphs(response.chart_name, response.min_price_usd,response.max_price_usd,response.factory_made,response.galenic_made,response.factory_made_max_min_graph_prices,response.factory_made_avg_graph_prices_stats,response.galenic_made_max_min_graph_prices,response.galenic_made_avg_graph_prices_stats);
                  }
              }


          }
        });


    });
   ```
2. in the response.rendered_page there is also this scripting that should
   a. change a text field with the value of the slider (it works)
   b. change the threshold horizonal line (it doesn't work)

   ```
   <script>
      // range slider code
      var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
      var output = document.getElementById("demo");
      output.innerHTML = 
      parseFloat(slider.value).toPrecision(2);//.toPrecision(- 
     Math.floor(Math.log10(slider.value))+2);

   slider.oninput = function() {

       var min_slider_value = parseFloat(this.value); 

       output.innerHTML = min_slider_value.toPrecision(2);
       chart.axisY[0].stripLines[0].set("value",min_slider_value);

   //console.log("TEST "+response.state);
   };

   var slider1 = document.getElementById("myRange1");
   var output1 = document.getElementById("demo1");
   output1.innerHTML = 
      parseFloat(slider1.value).toPrecision(2);//.toPrecision(  - 
      Math.floor(Math.log10(slider.value))+2);


   slider1.oninput = function() {

       var max_slider_value = parseFloat(this.value);        
       output1.innerHTML = max_slider_value.toPrecision(2);


   };
   ```
3. in a commonFunctions.js file loaded into the page before the postback there is the function for creating the graph where the relative variable chart has been defined as window.chart = new ...

   ```
    window.renderPriceGraphs = function(chart_name, min_price_usd, 
           max_price_usd, factory_made, galenic_made, 
                          factory_made_max_min_graph_prices, 
                          factory_made_avg_graph_prices_stats,
                          galenic_made_max_min_graph_prices = null,
                          galenic_made_avg_graph_prices_stats = null) {

   var max_line = max_price_usd*1.05;

   var min_line = min_price_usd*0.90;

   //alert("values "+max_price_usd+" "+min_price_usd);
   console.log("values ma and min"+max_line+" "+min_line);

   if(factory_made == true && galenic_made == true){

       //var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart(chart_name, {
       window.chart = new CanvasJS.Chart(chart_name, {
           animationEnabled: true,
           zoomEnabled:true,
           theme: "light2",
           title:{
               text: "Prices per unit of main active ingredients"
           },
           // subtitles: [{
           //   text: "High and Low Prices - 2016"
           // }],
           axisX: {
               valueFormatString: "MMM",
               intervalType: "month",
               interval: 1
           },
           axisY: {
               title: "Price (in USD)",
               prefix: "$",
               interval: 0.010,
               includeZero: false,

               stripLines:[
                   {                       
                       value: max_line,             
                       color:"#ff0000",
                       label: "Max threshold",
                       labelFontColor: "#ff0000",
                       showOnTop: true
                   },
                   {                       
                       value: min_line,             
                       color:"#00bc00",
                       label: "Min threshold",
                       labelFontColor: "#00bc00",
                       showOnTop: true
                   }
               ]


           },
           data: [

                   {
                       type: "rangeSplineArea",
                       showInLegend: true,
                       legendText: "Factory made max/min Prices",
                       xValueType: "dateTime",
                       xValueFormatString: "DD MMM",
                       yValueFormatString: "$#,##0.#######",
                       toolTipContent: "Factory made - {x}<br><b>Max:</b> {y[1]}<br><b>Min:</b> {y[0]}",
                       dataPoints: factory_made_max_min_graph_prices
                   },
                   {
                       type: "spline",
                       showInLegend: true,
                       legendText: "Average Factory Prices",
                       legendMarkerColor: "#dee0ec",
                       color: "#dee0ec",
                       lineColor: "#dee0ec",
                       markerSize: 5,
                       xValueFormatString: "DD MMMM",
                       yValueFormatString: "$#,##0.#####",
                       xValueType: "dateTime",
                       toolTipContent: "Factory made - <b>{x}</b> </br> Avg: {y}",
                       dataPoints: factory_made_avg_graph_prices_stats
                   },            


                   {
                       type: "rangeSplineArea",
                       showInLegend: true,
                       color: "#51bfc3",
                       fillOpacity: .3, 
                       legendText: "Galenic made max/min Prices",
                       xValueType: "dateTime",
                       xValueFormatString: "DD MMM",
                       yValueFormatString: "$#,##0.#######",
                       toolTipContent: "Galenic made - {x}<br><b>Max:</b> {y[1]}<br><b>Min:</b> {y[0]}",
                       dataPoints: galenic_made_max_min_graph_prices
                   },
                   {
                       type: "spline",
                       showInLegend: true,
                       legendText: "Average Galenic Prices",
                       legendMarkerColor: "#a6e6e8",
                       color: "#a6e6e8",
                       lineColor: "#a6e6e8",
                       markerSize: 5,
                       xValueFormatString: "DD MMMM",
                       yValueFormatString: "$#,##0.#####",
                       xValueType: "dateTime",
                       toolTipContent: "Galenic made - <b>{x}</b> </br> Avg: {y}",
                       dataPoints: galenic_made_avg_graph_prices_stats
                   },

           ]
       });
   }


   if(factory_made == true && galenic_made != true){
       var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart(chart_name, {
           animationEnabled: true,
           zoomEnabled:true,
           theme: "light2",
           title:{
               text: "Prices per unit of main active ingredients"
           },
           // subtitles: [{
           //   text: "High and Low Prices - 2016"
           // }],
           axisX: {
               valueFormatString: "MMM",
               intervalType: "month",
               interval: 1
           },
           axisY: {
               title: "Price (in USD)",
               prefix: "$",
               interval: 0.010,
               includeZero: false,
               stripLines:[
                   {                       
                       value: max_line,             
                       color:"#ff0000",
                       label: "Max threshold",
                       labelFontColor: "#ff0000",
                       showOnTop: true
                   },
                   {                       
                       value: min_line,             
                       color:"#00bc00",
                       label: "Min threshold",
                       labelFontColor: "#4b4b4b",
                       showOnTop: true
                   }
               ]

           },
           data: [

                   {
                       type: "rangeSplineArea",
                       showInLegend: true,
                       legendText: "Factory made max/min Prices",
                       xValueType: "dateTime",
                       xValueFormatString: "DD MMM",
                       yValueFormatString: "$#,##0.#######",
                       toolTipContent: "Factory made - {x}<br><b>Max:</b> {y[1]}<br><b>Min:</b> {y[0]}",
                       dataPoints: factory_made_max_min_graph_prices
                   },
                   {
                       type: "spline",
                       showInLegend: true,
                       legendText: "Average Factory Prices",
                       legendMarkerColor: "#dee0ec",
                       color: "#dee0ec",
                       lineColor: "#dee0ec",
                       markerSize: 5,
                       xValueFormatString: "DD MMMM",
                       yValueFormatString: "$#,##0.#####",
                       xValueType: "dateTime",
                       toolTipContent: "Factory made - <b>{x}</b> </br> Avg: {y}",
                       dataPoints: factory_made_avg_graph_prices_stats
                   },   
           ]
       });
   }

   chart.render();

   };
   ```

Looking to the console the error i get is

```
VM596:12 Uncaught ReferenceError: chart is not defined
at HTMLInputElement.slider.oninput (<anonymous>:12:9)
```

as if the chart object was not seen in the global scope. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Check your `factory_made` variable is it `true` or `false`. may be it is `false` and it is not satisfying any if condition and the `chart` variable is remains `undefined`

Comment: dear @Vibha Chosla thank you, but the chart is properly istianted and displayed, the problem appears when the slider movement event tries to call the chart.